# Get object reference, and function name

Tags: javascript, function, object

How can i retrieve the reference to object containing a function from an input in the form objectReference["functionName"].

Example:

```
function aaa(param) {
    var objectReference = /*..???...*/;
    var functionName = /*...???..*/;

    // Now expected result is that objectReference contains
    // a reference to myObject, and functionName contains a
    // string with name of function (implemented in myObject),
    // so I can invoke it with objectReference[functionName]()
    // after some manipulation.
}

var myObject = new SomeFunction();

aaa(myObject["myFunction"]);
```

Thank you

Comment: your question is not quite clear, please elaborate further

Answer (score 5):

You can't do either of the things you've listed. There are two separate things here:

1. Getting the `myObject` value
2. Getting the name of the property that that object uses to refer to the function

The value passed into `aaa` in your code is just a reference to the function. The reference to the object is not passed into `aaa`, nor is any information about what property the object used to refer to the function. Neither can be inferred or derived from the function reference itself. (The function may have a *name*, which could on modern JavaScript engines be access via its `name` property, but that may well be different from the name of the property that the object used to refer to it.)

In order to do this, you have to pass them separately, either as discrete arguments:

```
aaa(myObject, "myFunction");
```

or as an object

```
aaa({obj: myObject, prop: "myFunction"});
```

In the latter case, `aaa` might look like

```
function aaa(info) {
    // Use info.obj and info.prop here
    // The call would be
    info.obj[info.prop]();
}
```

Another option, if you don't really need the object reference except for the purposes of making the call, is to use `Function#bind`:

```
aaa(myObject["myFunction"].bind(myObject));
```

`aaa` will receive a function reference that, when called, will call the original function with `this` referring to `myObject`. So `aaa` can't actually get the object reference, but it can still make the call.

Comment: thank you, i hope to obtain this just passing one parameter, but is not possible clearly.

Comment: @Andrea: It can be one argument, but it has to be two pieces of information. I've added an example that uses an object so it's one argument, in case that's useful.